# How to move mouse pointer to element in Selenium with nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am working on nodejs, I have added selenium module.
right now I am stuck to click on button.
I must need to click by moving mouse pointer to element location.
And need to click it.
So an anyone tell me how we can use ActionSequence to move mouse at particular x y co-ordinates and hit mouse up and down with selenium.

I have searched but I am getting only Java related solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ActionSequence.mouseMove`? Other commands (`mouseUp`, `mouseDown`) you can find in https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_ActionSequence.html too

```
driver.actions().mouseMove(element).mouseUp().mouseDown().pe‌​rform()
```

or

```
driver.actions().mouseMove(element).click().perform()
```

Comment: I am new to selenium, can you please tell me how can I use it
Like :- driver.ActionSeauence.mouseMove(element).mouseUp().mouseDown().perform();
will it work?

Comment: I don't use selenium/nodejs, but I guess this should work: `driver.actions().mouseMove(element).mouseUp().mouseDown().perform()`. But if you only want to "moving mouse pointer to element location and then click it", you can try `driver.actions().mouseMove(element).click().perform()`

Comment: one more thing, I did same for text field
driver.findElemet(By.css('.class-name')).then(function(element){
     driver.actions().moveMouse(element).click().keyDown(element).sendKeys(element, 'some-text').keyUp().perform();
});

Its not working ....I want to click on textfield add/type text into textfield

Comment: for the text field, try this: `driver.findElement(By.css('class-name')).sendKeys('some-text)`

Comment: Just did ....
driver.findElement(By.css('.class-name')).sendKeys(args.firstName);

Comment: Hey can you please tell me ...is it correct or not ?
if(driver.findElement(By.css('.class-name')).getSize() > 0){

}

Comment: because I am not getting inside if block even if my page element contains that class!

How to check if an element present or not by class name ... I just need boolean value present or not .... how can I do this?

Comment: Those questions are quite out of the current question's scope. I believe that if you google a little bit you can find your answers, or if not, create a new question. :) I'm glad to help.

Comment: `Mousemove` is depreacted instead use `.move({origin: buttonElement)`